# How to cancel android phone call programatically

Tags: android

I found a lot of similar question but from a few years ago. I am wondering if the situation changed.

Android 8 brought a new method for answering the call through TelephonyManager. What about cancelling call? Is it possible to do it programmatically without having to use hacky ways?

Comment: Why just not check this using emulator?

Comment: @grabarz121 I don't understand could you explain?

Comment: Android Studio avd emulators has an option to simulate phone calls, just download right android image from sdk manager, run emulator and check does this older codes will work in api 26 or higher.

Comment: @grabarz121 Oh you meant that. I understand, thank you. I just wanted to know if something changed and if there is some less hacky way of doing it.